# Azure Search: How does Orderby treat null integer values?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an Azure Search Index that I'm hitting from an AngularJS app and I've run into a bit of a problem. One of my tables has a property that defines a "Sort Order" for the rows in the table, which is going to be used in the app to determine what order to display the items in the table to the user. Sort Order is an integer, and the goal here is when an admin user defines the "Sort Order" as 1, that item will appear first, 2 will appear second, etc.

My preferred solution would be to just sort the results from my query by ascending and spit that out to the user, but I've run into a problem with my null values, since Sort Order isn't a required field. All my models are written in C#, so null entries are being set to 0, and thus the entries without a sort order defined would be displayed first if ordered by ascending, which is the exact opposite of what I want.

There's a lot of different ways I could deal with this, but the easiest would be if I could just set the SortOrder property as a nullable int. The only problem with this is I'm not sure how Azure Search treats null values with its OrderBy statement. My initial thought was, if sorted by ascending, it would list all the numerical values in ascending order first, then kick the null values down to the end. If that's the case, then that's perfect, but I'm just looking to find out if that is indeed the case.

So, in short, my question is: Would Azure Search treat null values as greater than or less than a defined integer value? Put another way, if I OrderBy ascending integers, would the null values appear at the top or the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure search will place those documents whose $orderby column happens to be null towards the end of the results. This is true regardless of if you choose to order by "descending" or "ascending".

If there are multiple documents where the $orderby column is null, rest assured that all of them would be placed near the end, but you should ideally treat the ordering amongst the "null-valued" documents as undefined.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking to know. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add to my answer, there are certain occasions where there will be a definite ordering amongst null valued documents. If your query has no full-text component, ordering is not definite; if there are, relevance scores will be used to break ties and do the ordering.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the context. For this particular case, I don't care about the ordering of the null valued documents at all; they can be definite or not, it doesn't much matter. But I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I find the above answer wrong, as per my experience, If there are null values in the field, null values appear first if the sort is asc and last if the sort is desc.
You can refer the Azure documentation below for same [search-query-odata-orderby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-orderby)